# Lambda + Nodejs + dynamodb : storing json : Why put item storing data types?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm trying to store the json object in dynamodb using the code given below.

```js
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    var table = "Logs";

    id_val = 1
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Item: {
            "id": id_val,
            "message": event
        }
    };

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(null, JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            context.fail("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
    });
}
```

Input to event

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "demographic": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "middleName": "w",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "suffix": "jr",
            "birthDate": "1990-02-02",
            "gender": "M",
            "ssn": 123
        }
    }
]
```

What's stored in the table

```
{
    "id": {
        "N": "84.20420287568176"
    },
    "message": {
        "L": [
            {
                "M": {
                    "demographic": {
                        "M": {
                            "birthDate": {
                                "S": "1990-02-02"    
       ...
       ...
       ...
```

Why is datatype being stored in the table? How can one break this down so that attributes are stored separately?

Comment: Can you also provide your table schema for reference?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way dynamoDB stores data because when we look at the data we should be able to know the datatype of the field, which is excatly same as data type of column in relationa data base. Though data stores and displays like this in dynamoDB when we get data from dynamoDB through an actual application or API we can get rid of data types, which will return the actual data only.

Comment: Thank you. But when I create a record in dynamo db console or specifically with an attribute such as firstName:John in the items as part of the input parameter, the data type is not displayed in the console and that is because the put command now know the datatype before hand. The question is, for and input object that will have no defined schema, how does one write the put command so that each item is a separate attribute in the db?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was really busy :) . In REST world always there would be an agreement between client and service on how the data looks like. If you are planning to expose your service then ideally you should provide your clients on the data they supposed to send. Please check below link for a sample API documentation 
https://bocoup.com/blog/documenting-your-api

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't realize that I never thanked you. Better late than never I guess!

Comment: No problem buddy :)